# Add CASE statement column to existing GBQ table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-insert

Pretend I have a GBQ table:

```
SELECT 
'city_A' AS city,
15 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT 
'city_A' AS city,
17 AS score
UNION ALL
SELECT 
'city_B' AS city,
8 AS score
```

I want to add new column with CASE statement, like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 'city_A' THEN'LA'
    WHEN 'city_B' THEN 'PH' 
    ELSE NULL END AS iso_code
```

How to add/generate it ? With INSERT I only can insert blank column specifying all constraints, ain't I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an *update* here.  Assuming your table already have an `iso_code` column, then use:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET iso_code = CASE city WHEN 'city_a' THEN 'LA'
                         WHEN 'city_b' THEN 'PH' END
WHERE city IN ('city_a', 'city_b');
```

That being said, your `iso_code` column really feels like it could be a generated column, if BigQuery would support that.

Comment: Table do not have `iso_code`  column

Comment: ...then if you want to do this from a select then just add the `CASE` expression from my update to the select list.